# Как не позволить отправить форму если поле пустое

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Если `textarea` пустое то просто не отправлять форму js

Comment: return false; при сабмите, заставит прекратить проброс события (кажется).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Обработчик отправки формы
$('form').submit(function(){
  // Если textarea пустое
  if(!$(this).find('textarea').val()){
    // отменяем отправку
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо указать полю атрибут `required`.
Подробнее здесь: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/required

Answer (score 2):

1. Если форма отправляется самим браузером или по событиию `submit` на форме:

   - Использовать атрибут `required` (если есть IE пользователи - то только для версии 10+)
   - Использовать атрибут `pattern=".+"` (поддержка хуже, чем у `required`, поэтому менее предпочтителен, да и по семантике хуже)
2. Если форма отправляется из jquery-обработчика, или есть пользователи без поддержки выше-названных атрибутов, то можно использовать `event.preventDefault();` в теле обработчика события `click` или `submit`

Comment: А как это реализовать?